# How to wrap x and y around the screen?

Tags: c++

For example, if a moving ball goes beyond the screen, what is the exact method to do it?

I currently do this:

```cpp
if (x < 0.0) x = screenWidth() - 1;
else if (x >= screenWidth()) x = 0;
// same for y
```

But I saw this version:

```cpp
if (x < 0.0) x = x + screenWidth();
else if (x >= screenWidth()) x = x - screenWidth();
// same for y
```

Isn't the second version doing useless addition/subtraction?

Comment: Just guessing, but if `x == -10`, do you want it at `screenWidth() - 1` (first version) or `screenWidth() - 10` (effectively second version)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your version you just move the ball to the edge of the screen if it went out of it, but in the other version it keeps the distance that the balls travelled theoretically outside the screen to be considered in its new position. This helps to show the ball as travelling with the same speed.

Answer (score 2):

They do slightly different things: one does a cyclic wrapping (the second version) the other one just brings it to the edge (the first version).

Note that the code you are using for the cyclic wrapping may in general be wrong. Consider for example a `screen_size = 800;` and `x = -10000;`. Your code will bring it to `x = -9200`. You probably want to do `x = x % screen_size` before using your code for the cyclic wrapping, or you could use: `((x % screen_size) + screen_size) % screen_size` instead.

Comment: The result of `%` is negative if the first operand is negative.